# How to change Card-Group layout while in mobile mode - Bootstrap5

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am very new to responsive and web development in general and I am trying to make my website more responsive so that when the screen size is small enough my card group instead of going side to side, will become verticle.

I've had a look around and I can not find anything about it, any help would be great!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Lorem, ipsum.</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b5212ab333.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

        body{
          background-color: #212529;
          position: relative;
          margin-top: 50px;
        }

        #social-media{
          margin: 5px;
          padding: 15px;
          background-color: red;
        }

        #cards img{
          width: 100%;
          height: 250px;
        }

        #jumbotron{
          margin-top: 50px;
          height: auto;
          background-image: url("img/jumbo.jpg");
        }

        #jumbotron h1,p,button{
          padding: 5px;
        }

        #jumbotron button{
          width: 150px;
          height: 50px;
          font-size: 20px;
        }

        .center{
          text-align: center;
          margin: auto;
        }

        .social-link{
          font-size: 30px;
          float: left;
        }

        #footer{
          margin-top: 50px;
          background-color: #212529;
          padding-bottom: 50px;
        }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar" data-bs-offset="150">
    <div id="home">
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lorem</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#cards">About</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex" role="login">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="email" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Search">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-light" type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div id="jumbotron" class="mt-lg-0 p-2 bg-primary text-white center">
      <h1>Lorem, ipsum.</h1>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
      <hr>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor voluptas culpa blanditiis voluptatibus officiis voluptatem.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" href="#">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container text-white">
        <div class="row center mt-4">
            <h1>Lorem, ipsum.</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid modi pariatur quis, quia fuga voluptate.
            </p>
            <p class="secondary">
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque autem aliquam vero perferendis tenetur minus possimus et doloribus impedit! Aut officiis libero quas vitae sunt sed a accusantium hic nam.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="about" class="container text-white">
      <div id="cards" class="card-group">
        <div class="card mx-2 rounded border text-bg-light">
          <img src="img/pic1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up fa-1x" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>Card #1</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor dolore laudantium maiores iusto dolores obcaecati quo reiciendis! Odio, quos error consequatur numquam, eum iure, incidunt cupiditate provident non dolores esse..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mx-2 rounded border text-bg-light">
          <img src="img/pic1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>Card #2</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, assumenda delectus omnis nostrum tempore ut!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mx-2 rounded border text-bg-light">
          <img src="img/pic1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa-solid fa-clone" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>Card #3</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Beatae fuga, nemo quae et nobis unde deleniti praesentium nihil soluta, pariatur cupiditate autem? Libero eos odio asperiores odit placeat necessitatibus ducimus?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="end" class="center text-white" style="padding-top: 25px">
        <div class="row">
          <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, dicta.</p>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, a minima? Molestiae esse quidem praesentium.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="mt-lg-0 bg-dark text-center text-white">
      <!-- Grid container -->
      <div class="container p-4 pb-0">
        <!-- Section: Social media -->
        <section class="mb-4">
          <!-- Facebook -->
          <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#!" role="button"
            ><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i
          ></a>
    
          <!-- Twitter -->
          <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#!" role="button"
            ><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i
          ></a>
    
          <!-- Google -->
          <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#!" role="button"
            ><i class="fab fa-google"></i
          ></a>
    
          <!-- Instagram -->
          <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#!" role="button"
            ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i
          ></a>
    
          <!-- Linkedin -->
          <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#!" role="button"
            ><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i
          ></a>
    
          <!-- Github -->
          <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#!" role="button"
            ><i class="fab fa-github"></i
          ></a>
        </section>
        <!-- Section: Social media -->
      </div>
      <!-- Grid container -->
    
      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
        © 2022 Copyright:
        <a class="text-white" href="">Welshy</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->
    </footer>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want your cards to be side by side on mobile instead of stacked vertically?

Comment: No, I want them to be stacked vertically while on mobile. I am not sure how to do that (Sorry for the confusion)

Comment: They are already stacked vertically on mobile. The max width is 576px. Can you please specify the pixels you are testing your phone on?

Comment: I was using the different type of dimensions in Google Chrome